# Scala Pattern matching with tuple types

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

The following method throws an error, without even calling it.

```
type Checklist = (Int,String,Boolean)
  def higherthan(a: Checklist,b:Checklist) : Boolean = (a._1,b._1) match {
    case a._1 >= b._1 => true
    case a._1 < b._1 => false
    case _ => false
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Error:(3, 14) not found: value >=case a._1 >= b._1 => true
```

is it impossible to access the tuples' elements from pattern matching? I want to check which of the Checklist's first elements is bigger. Sorry for any mistakes, english is not my first language and I'm a first year student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways:

```
def higherthan(a: Checklist, b: Checklist) : Boolean = (a , b) match {
  case (x, y) if x._1 >= y._1 => true
  case _ => false
}

def higherthan(a: Checklist, b: Checklist) : Boolean = (a , b) match {
  case ((x, _, _), (y, _, _)) if x >= y => true
  case _ => false
}

def higherthan(a: Checklist, b: Checklist) : Boolean = a._1 >= b._1
```

Hope one of those helps.